# Botão bootstrap na mesma altura e posição em versões mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um sistema desenvolvido em Bootstrap do qual estou usando o seguinte código para criar um card baseado no [trabalho do colega do Bootsnipp](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/K3qgX):

```
<div class="card-base">
  <div class="card-icon"><a href="#" title="Widgets" id="widgetCardIcon"><img src="fotos-usuarios/silhuetaHomem.jpg" class="imagecard"></a>
    <div class="card-data widgetCardData">
      <h2 class="box-title" style="color: #000;">FERNANDO PESSOA</h2>
      <p class="card-block text-center">USUÁRIO<br>Acesso Padrão<br>Último acesso: 22/10/2017 às 11h11</p>
      <a href="#" title="Alterar Senha" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="background: #465768; border:#465768;"> <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Alterar Senha </a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.card-base>.card-icon {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.imagecard {
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  positioN: relative;
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}

.card-base>.card-icon>.card-data {
  margin-top: -24px;
  background: ghostwhite;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 15px 0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#widgetCardIcon {
  background: #465768 !important;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 78px;
}
```

Até aqui tudo certo, o resultado é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém quando tento alterar o atributo abaixo:

```
class="btn btn-primary col-sm-6 col-xs-12"
```

Vejam o que acontece:

**VERSÃO DESKTOP**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**MOBILE (360x640)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é: Como posso fazer para que em qualquer visualização, os botões mantenham a mesma altura e posição?

Comment: Qual é exatamente seu objetivo? que o botão assuma a largura máxima no mobile?

Comment: Largura máxima ele pega conforme a imagem 3. O objetivo é como informei no post: Como posso fazer para que em qualquer visualização, os botões mantenham a mesma altura e posição?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso o problema é que você incluiu no botão as classes `col-sm-6 col-xs-12`, e elas são utilizadas para definição de colunas do sistema de grid do bootstrap.

Não existe uma classe padrão no bootstrap para fazer os botões assumirem 100% de largura na resolução pequena, mas você consegue isso com um simples CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .btn, .btn-group {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

Segue abaixo seu exemplo com essa adaptação:

```css
.card-base>.card-icon {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.imagecard {
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  positioN: relative;
  width: 88px;
  height: 88px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: white;
}

.card-base>.card-icon>.card-data {
  margin-top: -24px;
  background: ghostwhite;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding: 15px 0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

#widgetCardIcon {
  background: #465768 !important;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: 78px;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .btn, .btn-group {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="card-base">
  <div class="card-icon"><a href="#" title="Widgets" id="widgetCardIcon"><img src="fotos-usuarios/silhuetaHomem.jpg" class="imagecard"></a>
    <div class="card-data widgetCardData">
      <h2 class="box-title" style="color: #000;">FERNANDO PESSOA</h2>
      <p class="card-block text-center">USUÁRIO<br>Acesso Padrão<br>Último acesso: 22/10/2017 às 11h11</p>
      <a href="#" title="Alterar Senha" class="btn btn-primary" style="background: #465768; border:#465768;"> <i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>  Alterar Senha </a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
</div>
```

Mais sobre o sistema de grid do bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Comment: Perfeito Diego. Funcionou. Muito obrigado.